# Error in `if_else()`: ! `false` must be a logical vector, not a double vector, but this variable must be numeric in R

Tags: r

Here is a data example:

```
scf=structure(list(MDM_Key = c(44L, 44L, 44L, 47L, 47L, 47L), month_id = c(202307L,
202305L, 202306L, 202307L, 202305L, 202306L), sale_count = c(NA,
73542L, NA, NA, 1852L, NA), prop_base_price_prc = c(0.05, 0.05,
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), subgroup_id = c("05,04,01", "05,04,01",
"05,04,01", "04,03,02", "04,03,02", "04,03,02"), ML.coef = c(1.43,
1.43, 1.43, 1.46, 1.46, 1.46)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```

I try to use this code:

```
scf %>%
  arrange(MDM_Key, month_id) %>%
  mutate(ML.coef = if_else(!is.na(sale_count), NA, ML.coef),
         percent = scf$prop_base_price_prc * ML.coef * 100,
         prop = (percent / 100) * sale_count[1],
         final = sale_count[1] + prop, .by = MDM_Key)
```

But I got the error

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `ML.coef = if_else(!is.na(sale_count), NA,
  ML.coef)`.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `false` must be a logical vector, not a double vector.
```

*ML.coef* is not a logical vector. It's numeric.
Where does this error occur and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that both the true and the false branch of `if_else` must have the same data type. The type of `NA` is `logical`. To use a numeric NA vector, you need to explicitly write `NA_real_` (`real` is an outdated synonym for `numeric`/`double`, but the name lives on inside the name of the numeric NA literal).

Alternatively, you should be able to fix the issue by updating your version of ‘dplyr’, since later versions (since v1.1.0) accept your current code as-is.